# Sqoop-Imported data is not shown in the target directory

Tags: sqoop

I have imported the data from MYSQL to HDFS with Sqoop but not able to see the imported data into desired given path.

Sqoop query is like -

`sqoop job --create EveryDayImport --import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books --username=root --table=authors -m 1 --target-dir /home/training/viresh/Sqoop/authors1234 --incremental append --check-column id --last-value 0;`

Comment: make sure you are using `-- import` not `--import` in your query.  Add `-verbose` in the command (_to see extended logs_) and share logs.

Answer (score 0):

sqoop job --create EveryDayImport -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books --username=root --table=authors -m 1 --target-dir /home/training/viresh/Sqoop/authors1234 --incremental append --check-column id --last-value 0

There is a mistake in your Sqoop statement that you missed to give space between "--" and import as mentioned in the comment by dev
Your sqoop statement use to create a sqoop job. To execute you job (sqoop import) you have to submit it by below statement.

$ sqoop job --exec EveryDayImport

I feel this is the reason no data present in your target dir